# How would I test if a player has an air block underneath their feet? (1.14)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm attempting to make a "midas touch"-eqsue system where the block underneath the player's feet will turn to a gold block. However, I found that'll be troublesome if I don't detect for air blocks, since that will basically allow for the player to jump and walk in mid-air.

My command is currently this;
`execute as @a at @s unless block ~ ~-1 ~ air run fill ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ gold_block`

Oddly, it's not looking for any (or simply isn't finding) any air blocks at all. It will detect other blocks and refuse to run there, eg. I replaced "air" with "diamond_block" and it worked in not turning diamond blocks, but it refuses to work with air.

Is this a known bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: It works for me. BTW, shorter version: `execute at @s unless block ~ ~-1 ~ air run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ gold_block`

Comment: not sure why you're using fill instead of setblock, but that command should work fine. are you in vanilla or on a third party server? and @FabianRöling, that one won't work from a commandblock, you'll need the `as @a` first.

Comment: @Plagiatus Almost. I meant `at @a` instead of `at @s`. `as` is not needed.

Comment: @Plagiatus i'm more familiar with fill rather than setblock, so i never really messed with it until recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have this problem, because you test the command in a cave. Minecraft has air and cave air, they are considered to be two different blocks.

To solve this problem you can use this command:

```
/execute at @a unless block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:air unless block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:cave_air run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:gold_block
```

Comment: I... was, in fact, testing it in a cave, and I didn't even know that existed. Thanks!

Comment: to make this a little better, you can add a blocktag with all the air in the game (there is air, cave air and void air afaik). See https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tag for more info on tags.

Answer (score 0):

try using execute @a ~~~ detect ~~-1~ frag 0 setblock ~~-1~ gold_block

and this is just for example replace frag with the block you want the player to step on